# JavaScript: Create a method in a key in an object if input of the main function exists

Tags: javascript, object, youtube-api, key

I am trying to create a variable Youtube Object that will be simulated in a for loop.

The concept is that I want to set a variable speed to each clip in a for loop. The idea is that YouTube takes in an object as described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#:%7E:text=This%20function%20sets%20the%20suggested%20playback%20rate%20for%20the%20current%20video.%20If%20the). This seems difficult.

I created the function here:

```
function YTObjects(videoId1, ...args) {
  let object1 = {
    height: "315",
    width: "560",
    videoId: videoId1,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      loop: 1,
      ...(typeof args[0] !== "undefined" && { start: `${args[0]}` }),
      ...(typeof args[1] !== "undefined" && { end: `${args[1]}` }),
    },
    if ((typeof args[2] !== "undefined") && (typeof args[3] !== "undefined")) {
      event: function (args[2], args[3]) {
        player.setPlaybackRate(args[2]*args[3]);
      },
    }
  };
  return object1;
}
```

Which enables me to create a variable object. But I am failing to create a function in a key that depends on the arguments (2&3).

Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: `function (args[2], args[3])` - That's not how function parameters work

Comment: So you know how destructuring works, and that there are template literals, ... but not how to define parameters of a function?

Comment: @Andreas If you know how to help that is great. Otherwise, please ignore this post as I am not writing my question to get negative remarks. Either give constructive remarks or do not comment at all. I would really appreciate that!

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> How to define a function, and what's the scope of variables are the two things you want to research (maybe in opposite order).

Comment: I do not know what you mean this is not the way functions are defined. Based on examples I see this was the way functions are defined. As you may see https://gist.github.com/cookpete/92eb0bf00704038061be0c9b08c18ae8#:~:text=YT.setConfig%20%3D%20function,if%20(c.hasOwnProperty(

Comment: You can't throw an `if` inside an object literal definition like that.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a ternary operator to conditionally assign the `event` property, or use an `if` after the object is defined.  You probably don't want any params in the anonymous function that's being added.

```
  let object1 = {
    height: "315",
    width: "560",
    videoId: videoId1,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      loop: 1,
      ...(typeof args[0] !== "undefined" && { start: `${args[0]}` }),
      ...(typeof args[1] !== "undefined" && { end: `${args[1]}` }),
    },
    event: ((typeof args[2] !== "undefined") && (typeof args[3] !== "undefined"))
      ? function () {
        player.setPlaybackRate(args[2]*args[3]);
      },
      : undefined
  };
  return object1;
```

or

```
  let object1 = {
    height: "315",
    width: "560",
    videoId: videoId1,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      loop: 1,
      ...(typeof args[0] !== "undefined" && { start: `${args[0]}` }),
      ...(typeof args[1] !== "undefined" && { end: `${args[1]}` }),
    }
  };
  if ((typeof args[2] !== "undefined") && (typeof args[3] !== "undefined")) {
    object1.event = function () {
        player.setPlaybackRate(args[2]*args[3]);
    };
  }
  return object1;
```

Comment: this is giving me undefined when you write in the console object1.events

Comment: Did you mean object1.event?  There is no property object1.events.